# svg draw circle with curved text inside

Tags: svg

I need to draw red cirle with two curved string inside like that:

[image]

upper string always be 3 chars length 
lower string can be from 1 to 20 chars length

**UPDATE1:**
I try to use textpath and circle tags, but I think I need to change some coordinates:

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    
        <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="24" style="stroke:#006600; fill:none"/>
     <defs>
            <path id="myTextPath"
                  d="M75,20
                     a1,1 0 0,0 150,0"
                    />
        </defs>
    
        <text x="5" y="50" style="stroke: #000000;">
          <textPath xlink:href="#myTextPath" >
                string
          </textPath>
        </text>
     
     
    </svg>
```

Also I didnt clear understand `<path>` 'd' atrribute , but I found out that I can change starting point to `M10,20` but how I can change text curve orientation?

```
d="M10,20 a1,1 0 0,0 150,0"
```

Comment: ...gets out his magnifying glass :)

Comment: You really need to show us what you have tried, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To have text that "hangs" from a line nicely, the best way right now is to use a path with a smaller radius.  There is an attribute to adjust the text's baseline, but that doesn't work reliably.

So you need two arcs. One for the bottom half of the circle, and one with a smaller radius for the top half.  They also need to both start from the left.  That means one will go clockwise, and the other will go anti-clockwise.  You control that with the arc command's "sweep" flag.

We need to also use `startOffset="50%"` and `text-anchor="middle"` to centre the text on the paths.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        viewBox="0 0 80 80">
    <defs>
        <path id="tophalf" d="M26,40 a14,14 0 0,1 28,0" />
        <path id="lowerhalf" d="M16,40 a24,24 0 0,0 48,0" />
    </defs>

 
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="24" style="stroke:#006600; fill:none"/>
    <path d="M16,40 a24,24 0 0,0 48,0" style="stroke:#600; fill:none"/>
    
    <text x="5" y="50" style="stroke: #000000;"
          text-anchor="middle">
        <textPath xlink:href="#tophalf" startOffset="50%">str</textPath>
    </text>

    <text x="5" y="50" style="stroke: #000000;"
          text-anchor="middle">
        <textPath xlink:href="#lowerhalf" startOffset="50%">second st</textPath>
    </text>

</svg>
```

This works fine in FF, but unfortunately, it seems there are bugs in Chrome and IE right now that is causing the text to not be centred properly on those browsers.

Comment: Testing in Safari and Chrome on macOS: it centres fine if you don't set `x="5"`.

Comment: Yes. Browsers have very inconsistent behaviour if you mix `x` and `startOffset` in textPaths. If you want to use `startOffset`, remove any `x` attributes from your `<text>` element.

Comment: Side note: With SVG 2 (implementation [in progress](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408)) you can define whether the text is rendered inward or outward with the new [`side`](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#text-TextPathElementSideAttribute) attribute on the [`textPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) element.